All-day event changes to a timed event
Here we use Google calendar all-day events to let others know when someone will be out. For ex: an all day event may be titled "Joe leaving at 3:00" The calendar will move the event to 3:00 and change the title to Joe leaving. I don't want that. How can this be turned off?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
